# Geometries to FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'd like to turn Google Earth Engine geometries to feature collection, however receive error message like:

```
Collection: Geometries cannot have their properties modified or be placed into collections.
```

How should I modify the code?
My code is following:

```
var glc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/wangq/test_slope')
var geometries = glc.geometry().geometries()
print(geometries)

var shape = ee.FeatureCollection(geometries)
print(shape)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections), a feature collection is a collection of features, and not a collection of geometries.

If you would like to combine geometries into a feature collection, first convert each geometry into a feature using

```
var features = geometries.map(function(g){
  return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry(g));
});
```

Then, combine the features into a feature collection using

```
var shape = ee.FeatureCollection(features)
```

[Link to complete code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4fb04f74789cbcc6e2d849d91cbc243e)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Pretty useful!